# Upgrade Firefox V79 in pi

Tags: firefox

I ran upgrade in terminal, I’m trying to see my ring video. It says upgrade to V79 in Firefox to see it.
Chromium says unsupported.
Is there a way for it to upgrade itself? Or manually do it?

Comment: what version of firefox are you running? Current version in bullseye is 102.4.0esr

Comment: Welcome.  If you still need help, please edit into your question *(do not just use comments)* the output from `cat /etc/os-release` and `file $(which file)`.